# Initialization of a member when passing parameters to a base class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

In the code below i'm assigning a value to uninitialized class member upon creation of a base class. Why didn't this cause runtime error?

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::string) {}
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar() : Foo(s = f()) {} // assigning to uninitialized class member

    void print() { 
        std::cout << s << std::endl; 
    }
    std::string f() {
        return "Some string";
    }

private:
    std::string s;
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    b.print();
    return 0;
}
```

But adding another one member to the class Bar produces an error on creation of the Foo class:

```
Class Bar {

// same as above

private:
    std::string s;
    int a;        // adding another member
};
```

Why do this happens?

Comment: The real question is: ***Why are you doing that?***

Comment: Welcome to undefined-behaviour-land, where *anything* can happen! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Runtime error"? There's no "runtime error" when assigning to an uninitialized member. In C++ the state of "being uninitialized" is not detectable at run-time, which is why it cannot possibly be handled in any deterministic manner (like with "runtime error").

When you do something like that, your code exhibits *undefined behavior*. The away this undefined behavior will manifest itself is unpredictable. It can easily be sensitive to completely unrelated factors, like declaring another member in the class. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug your code. It seems that, when you write:

```
Bar() : Foo(s = f()) {}
```

The `s` object is not properly created yet. Because constructor call of `Foo()` is not complete yet. Basically it is in a undefined state. So any behaviour will be undefined.
But this code behaviour is not undefined:

```
Bar() : Foo(/*anything*/) {
        s = f();
    }
```

Because the constructor call is complete.

---

Note: I tested in msvc11

Comment: @AlexEx it is undefined behaviour. you are sure of nothing

Answer (score 0):

When f() executes the class Bar is uninitialized so the member 'a' has no value. It's interesting that this code runs in visual studio 2008 but in any case this is not safe to do.

Razvan.

Answer (score 0):

Base class and class members are initialized in order of declaration (virtual base classes are different):

- Base classes (first) in order of declaration (Eg. class X : A, B, C }
- Members in order of declaration (Eg. int a; int b; int c;)

The order at initialization in a constructor does not change it.

In your case Foo is uninitialized, hence Bar and it's members - undefined behaviour (s has some rubbish data while assigning to it).